# FREETDS and UNIXODBC character converting

Tags: sql-server, linux, debian, freetds, unixodbc

ive got an error to fix. its:

```
[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Error converting characters into server's character set. Some character(s) could not be converted
```

when i use turkish characters to insert i get this error. my question is how can i disable that converting thing? im connecting to sql server via freetds and unixodbc.

thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set

```
clientcharset = UTF-8
```

in your freetds.conf file and read it from odbc.ini by setting the Servername option to the connection definition in freetds.com. See [this explanation](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2008q3/023604.html) and my [blog post](http://dirk.net/2010/09/18/sql-server-with-freetds-unicode-data-error/).

Comment: Thankyou! It has taken me many hours to resolve a similar issue. Who would have known that the client charset in the global section of freetds.conf was ignored.

Comment: Please note, that proper setting for TDS 8.0 is "clientcharset = UTF-8" - without whitespace. If I have known that, I would safe hours of searching...

Answer (score 2):

in python3, you need to add two lines after your conn

```
import pyodbc as db # forgot the imports
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=serv, database=db,port = prt,
                  uid=usr, pwd=passwd)
conn.setdecoding(db.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
conn.setencoding('latin1')
```